# Excel process not closing, Code runs every second time

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a some command buttons that send access tables through to an excel spreadsheet and undergo some formatting and entering some formulas in them. The other command buttons work, but this one falls over at the `LastRowInventory` line.

I am sure its something to do with `oBook` but I can't quite figure out how to fix it. I think its because it is attempting to get an object it has already got. It runs smoothly every second time, but does not close the excel process. My attempts at resolving this over the last couple hours have not worked.

The error I have been getting is as follows:

```
Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
```

Any help is appreciated. I believe it is a simple fix but just can't quite get it, I'm pretty new to programming. The code is below.

```
Private Sub INVENTORYLIST_Click()

DTable = InputBox("Input Table Name")
'****************************TRANSFER TO EXCEL********************************
Dim strWorksheetPathTable As String
    strWorksheetPathTable = "O:\GData\Downstream_LNG\Data Mgmt\CEDA\Reports\" & DTable & "\" & DTable & ".xls"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, _
    spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    TableName:=("" & DTable & "_INVENTORY LIST"), FileName:=strWorksheetPathTable, _
    hasfieldnames:=True, _
    Range:="InventoryList"


'****************************FORMAT INVENTORY SHEET***********************************
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim InventoryListSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SummarySheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("" & strWorksheetPathTable & "")
Set oBook = GetObject("" & strWorksheetPathTable & "")
Set InventoryListSheet = oBook.Sheets("InventoryList")
Set SummarySheet = oBook.Sheets("Summary")


With xlWB
    With InventoryListSheet
 'Some Spreadesheet Formatting in here
    End With
End With


'****************************CREATE OE STATUS BREAKDOWN CALCULATIONS ON SUMMARY SHEET**********************
Dim LastRowInventory As Long
LastRowInventory = oBook.Sheets("InventoryList").Range("A" & Rows.Count & "").End(xlUp).Row

With xlWB
    With SummarySheet
'Some Spreadsheet Formulas here
    End With
End With

'*********************************ORDER WORKSHEETS*************************************
With xlWB
    .Sheets("InventoryList").Select
    .Sheets("InventoryList").Move Before:=oBook.Sheets(1)
    .Sheets("Summary").Select
    .Sheets("Summary").Move Before:=oBook.Sheets(1)
End With

If Not SummarySheet Is Nothing Then
    Set SummarySheet = Nothing
End If
If Not InventoryListSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set InventoryListSheet = Nothing
End If
If Not oBook Is Nothing Then
    Set oBook = Nothing
End If
If Not xlWB Is Nothing Then
    xlWB.Save
    xlWB.Close
    Set xlWB = Nothing
End If
If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox ("INVENTORY SHEET HAS BEEN CREATED.")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LastRowInventory = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Or if that doesn't work try:

```
LastRowInventory = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Does this help you?

**EDIT:**

```
LastRowInventory = InventoryListSheet.Range("A" & InventoryListSheet.Rows.Count & "").End(xlUp).Row
```

By specifying the sheet that the rows are to be counted on the issue is fixed.

Comment: Do you receive the same Error?

Comment: InventoryListSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
does the same I guess?

Comment: When I try to recreate the problem by copying your code. Mine runs just fine, no errors at all. Do you have some more relevant details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66545/discussion-between-dane-i-and-wouter).